# SSRS reporting service error "Object Moved"

Tags: reporting-services, fba

I am getting SSRS reporting service error "Object Moved" when i call LoadReport method. I am using custom security.

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Reports/Pages/Auth.aspx? returnUrl=http://localhost//ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx" mce_href="/Reports/Pages/Auth.aspx? returnUrl=http://localhost//ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx">here</a>.</h2>
```

Comment: The problem is that the call made to the SSRS web service to render the report from Report Manager does not pass the custom cookie along, perhaps due to that you are referencing an invalid url. Therefore authorization fails and the request is redirected. This is the reason for the `"Object Moved"` message.

Comment: I don't understand what is invalid URL. It is wroking fine from Report Manager. However, programatically it fails on load report. Before, load report LogonUser execute successfully.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of digging and workarounds, i finally implement Custom authentication using reporting services SOAP API's. Trick is to pass authentication cookie along each request. Following article (though for report viewer but i take cookie management part) was very helpful;

http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/01/report-viewer-control-authentication_16.html

These lines after LogonUser do the cookie management part;

```
hcookie = new HttpCookie(myAuthCookie.Name, myAuthCookie.Value);  
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(hcookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not help other people, but I was able to fix this issue in Chrome by simply clearing my site data.

[image]